# Getting JSON element is not working when I try JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

When console logging the event object using `JSON.stringify(event)` I get the below output.

```
 {
    ...
    "body": "{\"vox\":{\"id\":10431,\"summary_text\":\"Vox received from 978-1913905101 via Book reviews at 17:17 (UTC) on 26/01/2022\",\"send_time\":\"2022-01-26T17:17:51.812Z\",\"contact_email\":\"\",\"contact_phone\":\"\",\"channel_name\":\"Book reviews\",\"channel_public_name\":\"telbee\",\"duration\":1,\"vox_context\":null,\"channel_id\":2786,\"recording_url\":\"https://api.telbee.io/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBczh6IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--9fdab42822e2a9235f03ca178ae917a83941b6cd/Wed%20Jan%2026%202022%2019-17-51%20GMT+0200%20(Eastern%20European%20Standard%20Time)\",\"direction\":\"vox_in\",\"channel_status\":\"active\",\"transcription_state\":\"not_transcribed\",\"share_link\":\"https://app.telbee.io/vox/Djw3em5mEMse6yjM5aA4S6oM\",\"vox_no\":2,\"sending_user\":null,\"contact_name\":\"978-1913905101\",\"contact_id\":6275,\"actual_transcription\":\"\",\"transcription_language\":\"en-US\",\"conversation_inbox_url\":\"https://app.telbee.io/inbox?token=iP9jHf2KVVrZuZRoe7n9NFLT\",\"sending_user_id\":null}}",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

But when I try to get the vox element of the body it fails

```
console.log('event body = ' + JSON.parse(event.body.vox.contact_name));
```

The error message is

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'contact_name' of undefined",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'contact_name' of undefined",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:49:69)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure how to get access to `event.body.vox.contact_name` even though I know it's there in the payload I cant get access to it. I know I have to parse it first as it is escaped but the console.log does not allow me to access the event objects body element.
I'm not sure what the issue could be as this is the event payload that is passed into this lambda function that I am creating and is attached to an AWS Gateway.

Comment: You're trying to use it before you parse it. The `body` property contains a string containing JSON, according to your `console.log`. So you parse it like this: `const body = JSON.parse(event.body);` then you access `contact_name` on the resulting object, `body.vox.contact_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a value before parsing.Try this

```
var body=JSON.parse(event.body);
var contactName=body.vox.contact_name; // 978-1913905101
```